# We cannot move yet we are the fastest. Who are we?

Tags: riddle

We cannot move yet we are the fastest. One of our brothers has even set the Guinness world record for speed.

We are often misunderstood. Yet in our world, we stand above everything else.

We can't say that everyone likes us. The blacks might like us. The whites might like us. But the black and white definitely adore us. Heck, they even need us.

Our names start with an explosion and end with the sound of an unhappy crowd.

Who are we?

Comment: I immediately though boom and boo, damn that bam!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> Bamboo  
>  As bamboo plants don't move from their roots but species of bamboo are the fast growing plants 
>  Often misunderstood as contains many of the letters of bamboozle 
>  Very tall plants in their environment  
>  Pandas (black and white) survive for nutrition from bamboo plants
>  Start with a 'bam' and end with a 'boo'

Comment: Oh man. You are good. Is it that easy? It took me a whole day to come up with that.

Comment: There are great clues in your question - giving so many helped  so much!

Comment: How does this satisfy the "Guinness world record for speed" clue?

Comment: http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/fastest-growing-plant/

Comment: Just a fun fact. They are 'misunderstood' because they are often regarded as trees but they are actually a type of grass and they are the tallest among all grasses

Answer (score 0):

## 71% of an answer

We are

> color(s)

We cannot move …

> Colors, *per se*, cannot move.

… yet we are the fastest.

> Colors are frequencies of light. 
> Light travels very fast; faster than anything else
> (except for hypothetical particles whose existence is unproved
> and which, even if they do exist, we can never detect).
> ***Also,***
> dyes that will not fade or be washed out are called ***color fast***.

One of our brothers has even set the Guinness world record for speed.

> Andy Green set the [land-speed (fastest car) record](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/land-speed-(fastest-car))
>  (measured over one mile).  Corroborated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_speed_record).

We are often misunderstood.

> ?

Yet in our world, we stand above everything else.

> The colors form the rainbow, which arches over the world.

We can't say that everyone likes us. The blacks might like us. The whites might like us. But the black and white definitely adore us. Heck, they even need us.

> Black is the absence of all color; white is the combination of all colors.

Our names start with an explosion and end with the sound of an unhappy crowd.

> ?

Comment: This is interesting. How do you explain 'black and white adore us'?

Comment: I was using the one explanation for the entire paragraph — just like the other answer does.  How does the accepted answer explain "The blacks might like us. The whites might like us."?

Comment: When i wrote the question, i was trying to say that the blacks (people) and the whites (people) MIGHT like 'us'. It can be argued that there is a probability they might like us. The accepted answer got the 'animal' part right though haha and in the end he got the 'what are we' right